# this on input and jquery(this) is not same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to get equivalent "this" in Jquery.

If I close my datePicker and I use the jQuery(this) in the InvalidMsg.

I got this error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'patternMismatch' of undefined
```

But if I keep the input empty and I submit the form. the InvalidMsg works perfectly.

it obscure but I have this input:

```
    <input type="text" name="birthday" 
           class="form-control date fulldate hasDatepicker" required="" 
           id="birthday" value=""
           placeholder="birthday" oninvalid="InvalidMsg(this,'Error dude.');"
           oninput="InvalidMsg(this,'error dude.');">
```

when I submit the form.. I have a custom message: "Error Dude."

This is the triggered function:

```
    function InvalidMsg(input,txt) {   
       if(input.validity.patternMismatch || input.validity.valueMissing || input.validity.rangeUnderflow || input.validity.rangeOverflow || input.validity.tooLong || input.validity.rangeOverflow){
           input.setCustomValidity(txt);
       }    
       else {
           input.setCustomValidity('');
       }
       return true;
    }
```

All works fine.

Now I have a datepicker on this input:

```
$('#birthday').datepicker({
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                var d = new Date();
                var day1 = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();                 
                var month1 = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getMonth();             
                var year1 = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getFullYear();
                var day2 = d.getDate();
                var month2 = d.getMonth();
                var year2 = d.getFullYear();

                console.log((month1).toString().length + " " + month1 );
                if(month1.toString().length < 2){
                    month1 = "0"+month1.toString();
                }
                if(month2.toString().length < 2){
                    month2 = "0"+month2.toString();
                }
                if(day1.toString().length < 2){
                    day1 = "0"+day1.toString();
                }
                if(day2.toString().length < 2){
                    day2 = "0"+day2.toString();
                }
                var e = year1+""+month1+""+day1;
                var f = year2+""+month2+""+day2;
                if(e>f || e.toString().length == 8)
                    InvalidMsg($(this),"Error Dude");
            }
        });
```

Any idea?

Comment: don't wrap this with a jQuery object...

Answer (score 2):

You have "this"

```
 InvalidMsg($(this),"Error Dude");
              ^^^^
```

You are wrapping it so it is a jQuery object, not the DOM element.

```
InvalidMsg(this, "Error Dude");
```

Comment: true, but the error not appear at the bottom of the current input "birthday"

Comment: @Jean-philippeEmond `$(this)` is a jQuery object, so it does not have the property such as `validity`, hence `input.validity` (`input` is the argument referring to `$(this)` passed in `InvalidMsg`) is `undefined`, and then the expression `input.validity.patternMismatch` raises the error ***Cannot read property 'patternMismatch' of undefined***.

Comment: So @Jean-philippeEmond did you try it?

Comment: @epascarello yes I'm trying to do a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/2019/ but the InvalidMsg is not trigger..
I have try without the $(). The msg error doesnt appears. like if he don't see the "input"

Comment: Issue one: Your fiddle has errors since it is not set up right.

Comment: And doesn't the error message only show up when the form is submitted? JavaScript changing a field's value does not trigger events.